# What would be the proper way to filter by date

Tags: javascript, datetime, filter

I have an array of objects with date strings formatted as so `2019-03-22T13:36:18.333Z`

I am curious what the best course of action would be to sort these by past day, past week, past month and past year.

I was thinking of just splitting at the `T` then splitting again at the `-`

I was also considering putting the date into the Date object and figuring it out that way.

What would be the most dynamic? Most efficient? etc.

```
const dates = [
  {created_at: '2019-03-22T13:36:18.333Z'}
  {created_at: '2019-05-22T13:36:18.333Z'}
  {created_at: '2019-03-23T13:36:18.333Z'}
  {created_at: '2019-03-24T13:36:18.333Z'}
  {created_at: '2019-01-22T13:36:18.333Z'}
]
```

```
const spliteDate = (date, splitBy) => {
  if(splitBy = 'day'){
    return date.split("T")[0].split("-")[1]
  } else if(splitBy = 'month') {
    return date.split("T")[0].split("-")[2]
  } else if(splitBy = 'year') {
    return date.split("T")[0].split("-")[0]
  }
}
```

```
dates.filter(date => {
  return splitDate(date, 'month') === Date.now().getMonth()
}
```

Something along these lines

Comment: What should the filtered output be?

Comment: Dates with a day, week, month and year of the current date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably the easiest to convert the strings to Date objects

For instance, you have an array of dates in string format:

```
const arr = ['2019-03-22T13:36:18.333Z', '2019-03-28T16:36:18.333Z', '2015-05-21T16:36:18.333Z'];
```

Looking at your question, if you would like to filter it by a certain date,  it is definitely much shorter and efficient to do this:

```
const filterByDate = dateFilter => arr.filter(date => new Date(date).getDate() < dateFilter);

filterByDate(25);
// result [ '2019-03-22T13:36:18.333Z', '2019-05-21T16:36:18.333Z' ]
```

And, if you require multiple filters, for instance filter by date AND year,

```
const filterByDateAndYear = (dateFilter, yearFilter) => arr.filter(date => (new Date(date).getDate() < dateFilter) && (new Date(date).getFullYear() < yearFilter));

filterByDateAndYear(25, 2018);

//result [ '2015-05-21T16:36:18.333Z' ]
```

Comment: That's amazing.  I was hoping to filter dates with a day, week, month and year of the current date.  I think I have enough information from your answer to see how much easier using the Date object would be.

Comment: You're welcome! Yup, but feel free to experiment with all the different ways to do things :)